# UIAlertController action crashes with error exc_bad_access while performing network oparation of 5 to 6 secs

Tags: swift

UIAlertController'  UIAction crashes with error exc_bad_access while performing network operation of 5 to 6 secs. Operation is performed successfully but crashes on last brace of UIAction with exc_bad_access error.

@IBAction func AddSceneCollectionViewOnClick(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        createAlertViewAddScene()
        present(uiAlertControllerAddScene, animated: true, completion: nil)

```
}

public func createAlertViewAddScene(){

    uiAlertControllerAddScene = UIAlertController(title: Constants.ALERT_VIEW_ADD_SCENE_TITLE,
                                                      message: Constants.ALERT_VIEW_ADD_SCENE_MESSAGE,
                                                      preferredStyle: .alert)


    let enterAction = UIAlertAction(title: Constants.ALERT_VIEW_ACTION_ENTER, style: .default, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in


        let textField = self.uiAlertControllerAddScene.textFields?[0]
        print("textfield data is \(textField?.text)")

            Manager.getIntance().roommanager!.addSceneToRoom(scene: scene, roomId : roomId!)
    })




    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    })


    uiAlertControllerAddScene.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = Constants.ALERT_VIEW_TEXT_FIELD_PLACE_HOLDER
    }


    uiAlertControllerAddScene.addAction(cancelAction)
    uiAlertControllerAddScene.addAction(enterAction)}


}
```

Comment: It would be better with codes! Please show your codes and error lines

Comment: And appropriate tags to the question. Swift is only a programming language and is not related to UIKit.